# Get a several counts using the same state of a list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have code like this:

```
count = taskList.Count(x => x.IsCompleted);
successfulCount = taskList.Count(x => x.IsCompleted && x.Result == true);
failedCount = taskList.Count(x => x.IsCompleted && x.Result == false);
```

I then use it like this:

```
Console.Write($"\r {count} out of {calls} calls made. {successfulCount} successful, {failedCount} failed.");
```

The problem is that the taskList is being updated in another thread.  So I end up getting messages like this:

> 48 of 777843 calls made.  96 successful, 0 failed

I know why it is doing this.  Between the time that I calculated the `count` and when I calculated the `successfulCount`, I had more tasks complete.

But it is still a bit odd to show to my tester (this is for a test harness), so, if it is possible to fix without slowing down what I am observing, then I would like to fix it.

Is there a way to issue 3 count calls in one query so it is more likely to have a consistent result?  (I does not seem likely, but I thought I would ask.)

Comment: Not sure if is the case but if the `taskList` is a `List<T>` it is not thread-safe. You could try using the `ConcurrentBag<T>` or `ConcurrentDictionary<T>` under the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace. Another option is to `lock` a static object to manipulate the list.

Comment: Take a *snapshot* `var current = taskList.Select(x => (x.IsCompleted, x.Result));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following

```
var result = taskList.Where(x => x.IsCompleted)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Result)
    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());

var successfulCount = result.TryGetValue(true, out var success) ? success : 0;
var failedCount = result.TryGetValue(false, out var failed) ? failed : 0;
var count = successfulCount + failedCount;
```

That will group the items in the list on the `Result` and create a dictionary of the counts.  Then you can get the success and failed counts and create the total by adding them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  My task list can be very large (200K tasks).  I like the idea of just capturing a dictionary of the counts.

Answer (score 1):

Just a variation on [juharr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/302918/juharr) worthy answer, Take a snapshot

```
var current = taskList.Select(x => (x.IsCompleted, x.Result)).ToList();
count = current.Count(x => x.IsCompleted)
successfulCount = current.Count(x => x.IsCompleted && x.Result == true);
failedCount = current .Count(x => x.IsCompleted && x.Result == false);
```

Comment: Did you mean to include a `ToList`, because otherwise that's going to iterate over the original changing list for each `Count` call.

Comment: @juharr ahh yup

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  I will fall back to this if the dictionary of counts does not work.  (My list can be 200K tasks long, so full snapshots could impact my load test.)